# Resetting an ostream, C++

Tags: c++, linux, iostream, ostream

I have 2 different ostreams, one of them cerr, using the same streambuffer, I have some libraries in that might have modified cerr somehow,(flags? format modifiers?).

```
cerr.rdbuf(&mystreambuffer);
ostream teststream(&mystreambuffer);

cerr << "This " << " is " << " a " << " test";
teststream << "This " << " is " << " a teststream " << " test";
```

prints:

```
This
is
a
test
This is a teststream test
```

Debugging `mystreambuffer` I've noticed that cerr calls `mystreambuffer->sync()` every `<<` operation while teststream does not call it at all.
If I am correct `cerr` is just an standard ostream, then, why do I see this difference in flushing times? How can I reset cerr back to normal flushing operations?

**EDIT:** I see you guys are commenting about unitbuf and it being default in cerr, but if it was default, wouldn't it write step by step here as well?

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::cerr << "This " << " is " << " a cerr " << " test\n";
    std::cout << "This " << " is " << " a cout " << " test\n";
}
Cobain /tmp$ ./test 
This  is  a cerr  test
This  is  a cout  test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `std::cerr.unsetf( std::ios_base::unitbuf );`. That flag is on for `cerr` by default.

Comment: See my update to the question, how can unitbuf be enabled on the new example?

Comment: @Arkaitz Jimenez: Flushing a stream doesn't necessarily mean writing a new line. What flushing does is to transfer the output characters from internal buffer to the final destination, e.g. to file in case of ofstream. What does your `mystreambuffer->sync()` do? Does it insert a new line among other things?

Comment: It works now with the unitbuf removed. I'm just trying to find if the libraries I'm using set the unitbuf in cerr or if this is definitely a default. I see that the standard says cerr is unbuffered, but the example I pasted doesn't show an unbuffered behaviour.

Comment: @Arkaitz Jimenez: I'm not sure why you think it's buffered. And yes, unitbuf in cerr by default is mandated by standard: 27.3.1/5 "After the object cerr is initialized, cerr.flags() & unitbuf is nonzero."

Comment: @Arkaitz Jimenez: Try this for example: `std::cerr << "This"; std::abort();`. Then replace cerr with cout and see if there is a difference.

Comment: @usta I see what you mean, I was confused with my framework inserting "\n" after each flush while the standard output obviously does not. Thx

Answer (score 1):

ios::unitbuf flag is the reason for that which is set to default for cerr.

You need to use the nounitbuf manipulator in order to fix it. Some older libraries may not have it, if so then use unsetf.

Edit: 
Default setting for unitbuf is implementation-dependent :)